# Should the s3 bucket has to be in same region to create the glue job

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue

When creating the Glue Job it has an option to select the custom script "S3 path where the script is stored" but it doesn't let to select the python scripts saved in other region s3 bucket it only allows to select the bucket and objects from the same region where we are creating the Glue Job. Is this a limitation of AWS Glue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the bucket from same region in which you are using Glue. I have tried providing a script from another region S3 bucket and encountered error as shown in below screenshot

[image]